# different class implementations based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I suppose this is trivial for people who know templates...

Suppose we want two different implementations of this template class, depending on the value of N:

```
template <int N>
class Foo {
    ...
};
```

For example:

```
template <int N>
class Foo {
    ... // implementation for N <= 10
};

template <int N>
class Foo {
    ... // implementation for N > 10
};
```

How can we do that in C++11?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use an extra template parameter with a default value to distinguish cases:

```
template <int N, bool b = N <= 10>
class Foo;

template <int N>
class Foo<N, true> {
  ...  // implementation for N <= 10
};

template <int N>
class Foo<N, false> {
  ...  // implementation for N > 10
};
```

Comment: Using a `std::conditional<N<=10, FooBaseLess<N>, FooBaseMore<N>>::type` as a base class would also work. But this is much neater, +1.

Comment: Thank you for: 1. Answering concisely and very usefully, 2. Not asking "Why would you want to do that?".