# Creating multiple class implemetations based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I have a templated class G:

```cpp
template<int I>
class G {}
```

And it's so happens that I need 2 implementations based on that `int I`

If it was a single value, I would always be able to do:

```cpp
template<>
class G<int Specific_I>
{
    /*Implementation for that I*/
}
```

If I had single condition, which shows to use implementation_1 if true and implementation_2 if false, I could've used advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491040/different-class-implementations-based-on-template-parameter)

---

But, my situation is more general.

Let's say I defined conditions on `I` for each implementation:

```cpp
template<int I>
constexpr bool Condition_1 = /*whatever*/;

template<int I>
constexpr bool Condition_2 = /*whatever_v2*/;
```

This allows for easy readability and expansion as needed
And if I get an error due to none or multiple of conditions applying for specific `I` when called in program, I'm fine with that

Obvious choice is to use `std::enable_if_t`

```cpp
template<int I,
enable_if_t<Condition_1<I>>
        >
class G
{
    /*Implementation based on Condition_1*/
}

template<int I,
enable_if_t<Condition_2<I>>
        >
class G
{
    /*Implementation based on Condition_2*/
}
```

But this causes an error

```
template parameter ‘typename std::enable_if<Condition_1<I>, void>::type <anonymous>’|

redeclared here as ‘typename std::enable_if<Condition_2<I>, void>::type <anonymous>’|
```

Where have I made mistake and how do I fix that?

Comment: I swear, if I get a "duplicate" tag that links to a question I've already explained as "didn't solve my problem"...

Comment: the question is rather unclear. You want different definitions for say `I==0` and `I==1` ?

Comment: you defined the same template twice as the error tells you, but its not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 As I've stated, I have `constexpr` conditions for `I` in each implementation

Comment: "in each implementation" what does that mean? you have `Condition_1` and `Condition_2` and you want to choose the implementation based on whether one of them is `true`?

Comment: what if both are  `true`?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 think about them as `I < -50` in one and `I % 2 == -1` in another, or something like that. No relation guaranteed. No intersection rules guaranteed

Comment: if both are true, I agree for an error (but only if I specifically write smth like `G<-51>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that you didn't adjust the primary template to use the idiom correctly. If you want to add those `enable_if`'s that resolve to `void`, the primary template declaration needs a type parameter in that place:

```
template<int I, typename = void>
class G; // Or static_assert in the definition. Whichever flavor you prefer.

template<int I>
class G< I, enable_if_t<Condition_1<I>> >
{
    /*Implementation based on Condition_1*/
};

template<int I>
class G< I, enable_if_t<Condition_2<I>> >
{
    /*Implementation based on Condition_2*/
};
```

Note: the default argument must be `void` for your specializations with the condition to match. This will  of course result in an error when both conditions hold, but you did assert that's fine with you, so there you go.

Comment: ooh, of course... I'm going to input only 1 parameter, so there must be only `int I` inside brackets of `template`

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. I would remove the definition of the primary `G` (or put a `static_assert` in there) to cover (as in, produce an error in) the case of no condition being satisfied. But this answer seems perfect.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Ah I see, so this is because you do not understand partial ordering and what goes in the template's signature. Why didn't you just say so? I can explain

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - I did, [of course](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f1daace4dc2f545). Did your attempt satisfy both conditions?

Comment: Of course I triggered both conditions because they are independent conditions. If they are not, they shouldn't be 2 different conditions and your solution doesn't make sense. The question wants 2 different implementations for different conditions, and your solution doesn't provide for that. Not to mention that `enable_if_t` is unnecessary here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Then I suggest you read the question again. The OP wants an implementation when exactly one condition holds, or an error otherwise. This solution makes perfect sense, if one even bothers to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `std::enable_if` for this problem. Since your conditions are independent they should initialize a different template parameter:

```
template<int I, bool C1 = Condition_1<I>, bool C2 = Condition_2<I>>
struct G;

// Specializations for different conditions.
template<int I> struct G<I, false, false> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I, false,  true> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I,  true, false> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I,  true,  true> { /*...*/ };
```

Alternatively, you can compose conditions into one parameter:

```
template<int I, unsigned C = (Condition_1<I> | Condition_2<I> * 2)>
struct G;

// Specializations for different conditions.
template<int I> struct G<I, 0> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I, 1> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I, 2> { /*...*/ };
template<int I> struct G<I, 3> : G<I, 2> { /*...*/ }; // Same as G<I, 2>.
```

Comment: Now imagine 5 implementations, each with its own condition. 10? Your solution does not scale.

Comment: But... it can actually  be useful if I need to track each combination of conditions. Is there a way to combine some of combinations? (i.e. make false-false and true-false refer to same implementation without copy-pasting) (and I mean without sub-template that gets rid of single parameter, because that would disallow combining two pairs for example)

Comment: Ok, I rethought your approach. I still think it does not scale (strictly due to readability). But I think it does allow combining if done carefully

Comment: @NooneAtAll Added an alternative for you.